# Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext loading xml

Tags: java, spring

Now I want to load `applicationContext.xml` by `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, my working folder structure is `src/main/java;`  `src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml;`

My code is

```
ApplicationContext ctx =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml");
```

Throw cannot be opened because it does not exist,but

```
    ApplicationContext ctx =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

is ok, Why is it happen?

Comment: Try `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");`

Comment: @JaySmith, he already said that "new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");" is working fine, but question here is "why its working?"

Comment: Because in maven project `src/main/resources` is source folder. Java files from `src/main/java` and resources are compiled into `target/classes` folder.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198095/spring-classpathresource-cannot-be-opened-because-it-does-not-exist

Answer (score -2):

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` will look for specific file from the `classpath`. From the `Java Build Path -> Source` section, you can see the source folders: src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java. They will be used as classpath by the java applicaiton.

So if you pass  `applicationContext.xml` as parameter, jvm will look for this file from the above 3 folders. `src/main/resources/beanConfigurationName.xml` will lead jvm to look for `"src/main/resources/beanConfigurationName.xml"` from classpath.